# strange Ant build failure

Tags: java, ant, build

I'm getting this error when I run `ant compile`:

```
[javac] Compiling 9 source files to /home/wena/work/workspace/PortalMapper/build/classes
[javac] /home/wena/work/workspace/PortalMapper/src/foo/esb/portal/service/PortalRequestBroker.java:439: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method setLeadId(java.lang.String)
[javac] location: class foo.crmservice.DepositRequest
[javac]             depositReq.setLeadId(portalDepRequest.getLeadId());
[javac]                       ^
[javac] 1 error
```

Here's a snippet of my ant build file:

```
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${dir.java}" destdir="${dir.classes}">
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

**depositReq** is an instance of a class where we have:

```
private String leadId;
public void setLeadId(String leadId) {
    this.leadId = leadId;
}
```

**portalDepRequest** is an instance of a class where we have:

```
private String leadId;
public String getLeadId() {
    return leadId;
}
```

**notes**:

- The project doesn't show errors on Eclipse.
- I'm using **sun-java6-jdk** on Debian (if that matters)

Comment: What is classpath.mule? Did you do a clean as wel?

Comment: @navi that was just the name the classpath id.

Comment: can you post the declaration of setLeadId() from the class. It is complaining about the method and not the entire class. Possible mismatch in arguments?

Comment: what does portalDepRequest.getLeadId() return?

Comment: Ups, sorry, that was obvious from the error message. The message is saying that class DepositRequest does not have a method called setLeadId() taking a String argument, so I'd double-check that. Why would the error show only when using ant I've no idea. Different libraries/paths/compiler options?

Comment: @agnul It's very likely different libraries/paths/compile because  I've double-checked those 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `cannot find symbol` error occurs when using `javac` if a dependency for the compiled source code is not on the classpath. In your case this appears to be the class `foo.crmservice.DepositRequest`.

Since it compiles in Eclipse, have you explicitly included this class in a referenced library? Or perhaps by linking another project?

Comment: The class `foo.crmservice.DepositRequest` is part of the same project (where I'm building from). So there's no need to include it.

Comment: Is it in the directory specified by `${dir.java}` ?